# How to effectively test deployment script

Tags: 10.04, installation

I'm developing a script for my company that installs all the dependencies we have and sets up some of the software. I need some way to effectively test my script on a clean machine over and over. Is there some way to "reset" the system to the state it was in when it was just installed? Or would the best approach be to have a virtual machine that I can reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with a virtual machine and saving/restoring the state. It's works very well for my purposes at least. It's a bit slower when building a lot of stuff, but you can have multiple "startpoints" depending on what part of the script you're tweaking...

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to clone / backup your existing installation. When you need a clean state, just clone the image back to your hard disk. Example guide can be [found here](http://johnsalim.blogspot.com/2010/08/cloning-harddisk-with-ubuntu-1004.html).